# Как обратиться к элементам списка со вложенным словарем для вк апи делаю стэндалон приложение?

Tags: python, list, dict

К примеру имею такой вывод в `json`, хочу отфильтровать вывод по `key=country`, чтобы по стране фильтровал.Вывод о 3 пользователях группы вк, хотел вывести только тех, кто в Махачкале.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers",{
            'group_id':group_id,
            'count':1000,
            'offset':0,
            'fields':fields,
            'access_token':Token,
            'v':5.73}).json()

ids = response['response']['items']
for item in ids:
    print(item['id'])
```

По `key` `'id'` выдает, а по стране ошибка: `KeyError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-1e39321e566f> in <module>()
     52 #print(ids)
     53 for item in ids:
---> 54     print(item['country'])

KeyError: 'country'
```

Пробовал этот вариант:

```
for item in ids:
    print(item['country']['title'])
```

Тоже нет:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-64d989cdca15> in <module>()
     52 #print(ids)
     53 for item in ids:
---> 54     print(item['country']['title'])

KeyError: 'country'
```

---

Я вывел ids перед циклом, поле страна есть с title:

> [{'id': 945747, 'first_name': 'Don', 'last_name': 'Chucha', 'sex': 2,
> 'bdate': '29.5.1984', 'city': {'id': 85, 'title': 'Махачкала'},
> 'country': {'id': 1, 'title': 'Россия'}, 'photo_200_orig':
> 'https://pp.userapi.com/c621924/v621924747/d7af/80bQh4EYx8g.jpg',
> 'online': 0, 'home_phone': 'нет', 'common_count': 0, 'university': 0,
> 'university_name': '', 'faculty': 0, 'faculty_name': '', 'graduation':
> 0, 'relation': 0, 'universities': [], 'schools': [{'id': '42458',
> 'country': 1, 'city': 85, 'name': 'Школа №28', 'class': ''}, {'id':
> '50041', 'country': 1, 'city': 85, 'name': 'Школа №30', 'class': ''}],
> 'relatives': [{'id': 32707721, 'type': 'sibling'}]}]

А это полный json:

> запрос {'response': {'count': 727, 'items': [{'id': 945747,
> 'first_name': 'Don', 'last_name': 'Chucha', 'sex': 2, 'bdate':
> '29.5.1984', 'city': {'id': 85, 'title': 'Махачкала'}, 'country':
> {'id': 1, 'title': 'Россия'}}]}}

Проблема в том,что цикл выводит страну первого id, для остальных он пишет `KeyError`

Help friends!)

Comment: `KeyError: 'country'` означает что не такого ключа. То есть `ids` у вас не такие как в примере показано. Напечатайте `ids` перед циклом, чтобы убедиться.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том, что не всегда в данных было поле `country`, поэтому в пример добавил `try`/`except KeyError` для игнорирования таких случаев

Использовал полный `json` из вопроса:

```
rs = {'response': {'count': 727, 'items': ...

for item in rs['response']['items']:
    try:
        print(item['country']['title'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

---

Использовал значения из `ids` из вопроса:

```
items = [{'id': 945747, 'first_name': 'Don', ...

for item in items:
    try:
        print(item['country']['title'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: У меня та же ошибка keyerror country, хотел уточнить у вас выводит страну для всех items в переменной items?Pls help people!)

Comment: У меня та же ошибка keyerror country, хотел уточнить у вас выводит страну для всех items в переменной items?Pls help people!)

Comment: Я разобрался, оказывается не во всех item было указано поле страна, я применил try / except все пошло как по-маслу) Спс ребята!)

Comment: @john.jk1 что-то я пропустил ваш комментарий за 24/04. Хорошо что разобрались с проблемой, ответ обновил